# Form submit using Python lxml

Tags: python, html, xml, forms, lxml

I have a login page which is like this

```
<form method="POST" name="DefaultForm" action="SOME_URL" onSubmit="return (isReady(this));" autocomplete="off">

<input name="action" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">
<input name="serverTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">
<input name="clientTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="clientIP" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">

<TABLE height="400" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="540" align="center" background="images/bkground.gif" border="0">
...
<INPUT class="inputStyle" type="Input"  name="username" size="20">
<INPUT class="inputStyle" type="password"  maxLength="28" name="password" size="20">
...
</TABLE>
</form>
```

Using Python and lxml/Requests modules

```
session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
if tree.find('form') :
print "do something"
else :
print "do something else"
```

but I am not able to get this to work, the find() always returns **None** always comes to else block. Can someone  suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Why you see none is because the form is the *root* element:

```
    h = """<form method="POST" name="DefaultForm" action="SOME_URL" onSubmit="return (isReady(this));" autocomplete="off">

<input name="action" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">
<input name="serverTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">
<input name="clientTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="clientIP" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">

<TABLE height="400" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="540" align="center" background="images/bkground.gif" border="0">
<INPUT class="inputStyle" type="Input"  name="username" size="20">
<INPUT class="inputStyle" type="password"  maxLength="28" name="password" size="20">
</TABLE>
</form>"""

x = html.fromstring(h)
print(x.attrib)
print(x)
print(x.find("form"))
```

Just doing the above:

```
{'action': 'SOME_URL', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'onsubmit': 'return (isReady(this));', 'method': 'POST', 'name': 'DefaultForm'}
<Element form at 0x7f2b9c28eb50>
None
```

If we wrap the form in a div:

```
h = """<div>
      <form method="POST" name="DefaultForm" action="SOME_URL" onSubmit="return (isReady(this));" autocomplete="off">
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">
<input name="serverTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">
<input name="clientTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="clientIP" type="hidden" value="SOME_VALUE">
<TABLE height="400" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="540" align="center" background="images/bkground.gif" border="0">
<INPUT class="inputStyle" type="Input"  name="username" size="20">
<INPUT class="inputStyle" type="password"  maxLength="28" name="password" size="20">
</TABLE>
</form>
</div>"""

from lxml import html
import lxml.etree as et
x = html.fromstring(h)
print x
print(x.find("form"))
```

Now the div is the root and *find*, finds the form:

```
<Element div at 0x7f05966b3b50>
<Element form at 0x7f0597a44ba8>
```

Comment: Hi Padraic Cunningham, Thanks for the response. but the page is on a web server so i cannot modify the html. The form is actually wrapped under a html and table tag i.e. <html><table><my_form>...</my_form></table></html>

Comment: @Gauss,  I just wrapped the html in a div to show you the difference,  when you `print tree` what do you see?